# Show that $T \in \text {GL} (\mathcal H).$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

> Let $T_n, T \in \mathcal L(\mathcal H)$ with $\lim\limits T_n = T.$ If $T_n \in \text {GL} (\mathcal H)$ for all $n$ and $\sup\limits_{n} \left \| T_n^{-1} \right \| \lt \infty$ then $T \in \text {GL} (\mathcal H)$ and $\left \|T_n^{-1} - T^{-1} \right \| \to 0.$

What I realized that in order to show that $T \in \text {GL} (\mathcal H)$ we need only to show that $T$ and $T^*$ are injective and their ranges are closed. Since $T_n \to T \iff T_n^* \to T^*$ by symmetry it is enough to show that $T$ is injective and $\text {ran} (T)$ is closed. It is also enough to show that $\text {ran} (T) = \mathcal H.$ Then using the identity $$T_n^{-1} - T^{-1} = T^{-1} (T_n - T) T_n^{-1}$$ we can conclude that $T_n^{-1} \to T^{-1}.$ But I am having hard time showing these things. Could anybody please help me?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: This basic result can be found in almost any book on FA.

Comment: Could you suggest me any such @Kavi Rama Murthy?

Comment: I think this question at least answers half of your question: [Criterion for a limit of invertible operators on a Banach space to be invertible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160033/criterion-for-a-limit-of-invertible-operators-on-a-banach-space-to-be-invertible)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $:$ Show that if $T_n \in \text {GL} (\mathcal H)$ for all $n$ then $\left \{T_n^{-1} \right \}$ is Cauchy using the resolvent identity you have mentioned. So it will converge to some $S \in \mathcal L (\mathcal H).$ Then show that $ST = TS = I$ and you are through.

To show that $ST = TS = I$ you may use the following fact $:$

> If $S_n,T_n,S,T \in \mathcal L (\mathcal H)$ for all $n$ with $S_n \to S$ and  $T_n \to T$ then $S_n T_n \to ST.$