# Perturbations of semi-Fredholm operators

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm trying to understand the proof in Chapter 18, Corollary 2, of "Spectral Theory of Linear Operators and Spectral Systems in Banach Algebras" by Muller, of the fact that a small bounded perturbation of an operator which is upper (lower, resp.) semi-Fredholm but not Fredholm remains upper (lower) semi-Fredholm but not Fredholm. This follows from the result of the preceding Lemma 1, which states that operators at the boundary of Fredholm operators are not semi-Fredholm. Unfortunately, I cannot make sense of a step in the proof of this Lemma, and am hoping that someone here can.

He takes a sequence of Fredholm operators $T_n$ which converge to a bounded non-Fredholm operator $T$. Then he applies a construction to obtain isomorphisms $\tilde T_n$ which converge to a non-Fredholm operator $\tilde T$ and concludes that $\tilde T$ is neither injective nor surjective. I do not understand this step: I understand that if $\tilde T$ were both injective and surjective then it would be an isomorphism, but why can't it be one but not the other?

I'm aware of [Criterion for a limit of invertible operators on a Banach space to be invertible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160033/criterion-for-a-limit-of-invertible-operators-on-a-banach-space-to-be-invertible), which implies that the operators $\tilde T_n^{-1}$ are diverging in norm. But I'm not sure if this helps.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I think that the above link actually is quite useful. I believe that it implies that if $\tilde T_n$ are isomorphisms which converge to a bounded operator $\tilde T$ which is not an isomorphism, then $\tilde T$ is neither bounded below nor surjective. And this would complete the argument, since Muller showed that $\tilde T$ is bounded below iff it is injective. So, let me rephrase my question: is there an easier way to conduct this argument (Muller seems to think it is easy/obvious, as he does not elaborate)?

Proof of the claim at the start of the edit: we know from the linked post that $\|\tilde T_n^{-1}\|\to \infty$, so there are unit vectors $w_n$ such that $\|\tilde T_n^{-1} w_n\| \to \infty$. Rescaling gives vectors $\tilde w_n$ such that $\|\tilde T_n^{-1} \tilde w_n\| = 1$ and $\tilde w_n \to 0$. Defining $v_n = \tilde T_n^{-1} \tilde w_n$, we have $\|v_n\|=1$ and $\tilde T_n v_n \to 0$. Since $\tilde T_n \to \tilde T$, this implies that $\tilde T v_n \to 0$. So, $\tilde T$ is not bounded below. By duality, we learn that $\tilde T$ is also not surjective.